# PDF/A document with data is downloading incorrectly on Windows/Chrome. Have to open in Apache Acrobat Pro and save to fix

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfa

I am not sure how to phrase this question. We have code that creates a PDF that is PDF/A compliant, we put in some xml data into the metadata section. We then display the PDF in a preview window where the user can download the PDF. As part of our users process they open up the PDF in a text editor and search for one of the xml tag, "vendor" while all the data is encrypted, the tag value of "vendor" is still visible, such that the search would work. And then the users submit these files to US Courts that export the data.

I am on a Mac and I follow this process and it works perfectly.

The issue we have is that on Chrome/Windows users when they download the PDF and try to search for "vendor" it doesn't work. The search fails. If the user opens up the document in Adobe Acrobat Pro and then just hit Save, then open it in their Text editor it then works. The problem is our users are now complaining about having to do those two extra steps.

This only occurs on Windows users with Chrome. It does not happen on Mac/Safari.

I wish I could attach a sample, but the documents are extremely confidential, and I can't make one up with non confidential data as that would then not match what happens in our application.

Comment: You need to add a lot more information, like an example pdf, and exactly which text editor on which version of Windows and which version of Chrome. Essentially, everything anyone could need to reproduce your issue. It is very likely that opening a PDF file with a plain text editor will corrupt the file. Also, while the file initially may have been created with iText, there is nothing in your problem description that indicates that iText is anywhere involved, so please explain why you added the tag. Also, you need to explain why your users need to use that workflow.

Comment: I just noticed the last paragraph, that you cannot share a file because of confidentiality. That makes it impossible to answer your question. However, if you are a customer of iText Software and have a support contract, then a Non Disclosure Agreement can be arranged. Contact iText Software for more information.

Comment: *"I can't make one up with non confidential data as that would then not match what happens in our application."* - I don't understand. After all you create the PDFs in question with your code. So you should be able to run the code with demo data. And if it turns out that PDFs with demo data instead of real data don't show the issue, then how should anyone help you without the real pdf?

Comment: Thanks Amedee. Yes we have paid for iText. The text editor is wordpad on Windows 10. Chrome auto updates, so any version over the past year.

Comment: mkl, there is more proprietary stuff in the PDF beyond the xml data too. I know how it makes things more difficult, but I think someone else has to have had this same issue before and found a resolution. My hands are tied to as much as I could post in the question.

Comment: Don't display in preview and then download. Do a direct download in all browsers. Could be Chrome viewer.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Do you think only the Chrome Viewer in Windows and that Mac is different? I will ask the business team if that is acceptable, unfortunately, I think the clients like previewing it in the browser first, BUT we might be able to change the previewer to a product Prizm Doc which we use for other previewed documents.

Comment: @KevinBrown Thanks again, we just added exactly that feature to download it directly and get the same incorrect results. I have since opened up a Jira ticket on iText's support site and will report back if we find a resolution. FYI, if you open the pdf in Acrobat Pro and just click Save As to save it, it fixes the file, but our users won't stand for 2 more steps to their process.